# Introspect type min/max with C

Tags: c, types, c-preprocessor

I was wondering if there was some way in C, to introspect the maximum of a type.

So for example I have a variable called `a` which is an `unsigned short`...

```
{
    unsigned short a;
    long long max = TYPEOF_MAX(a);
    /* now max will be USHRT_MAX */
}

{
    signed char a;
    long long max = TYPEOF_MAX(a);
    /* now max will be CHAR_MAX */
}
```

Where `TYPEOF_MAX` is a macro which uses some method to get the range based on in type (which is static).

Other qualifiers...

- Its OK if this is limited to a few types, eg `char/short/int/long/long long/float/double`
- This may need to use some C extensions, GCC or maybe even C11, though more portable methods are preferred.

*Note: This is for use with generated code, obviously including `<lmits.h>` and using `USHRT_MAX` and `CHAR_MAX` works fine in almost all cases*.

Comment: `#include <limits.h>` then use `INT_MAX` etc. If you have a non-builtin but unsigned type `T`, you can also use `((T)-1)` to get the maximal value.

Comment: and? did I post it as an answer?

Comment: C11 is three years old already... the sooner you Go Forth And Code in it, the sooner people will stop thinking of it as anything strange. In fact, that's a good reason to prefer the C11 solution. If it doesn't work, bug your compiler vendor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never did c11, however it does have a feature that could help you, according to wikipedia called "Type-generic expressions". From what I understand, you can do `_Generic(a, int: INT_MAX, long: LONG_MAX, default: SOME_MANINGFUL_DEFAULT_VALUE)`. This will inspect the type of a and according to its type, select some expression to evaluate, which will be the result of the type-generic expression.

It's not the best solution, but all you gotta do is have a macro which uses _Generic and deals with all the arithmetic types you're interested in.

GCC 4.9 (https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status) seems to support it.

The wikipedia page might explain it better than I did: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution that uses GCC's `__builtin_types_compatible_p`, While it works it has the following drawbacks.

- GCC Only (no MSVC)
- Missing types won't fail at build time (instead at runtime).
- Can't be used outside of a function.
- Not considered a constant, so you can't use with static-assert for example.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

#define TYPEOF_MAX(x)                                                         \
  ({                                                                          \
    typeof(x) tmp;                                                            \
    if      (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), signed char))            \
      tmp = (typeof(x))CHAR_MAX;                                              \
    else if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), unsigned char))          \
      tmp = (typeof(x))UCHAR_MAX;                                             \
    else if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), signed short))           \
      tmp = (typeof(x))SHRT_MAX;                                              \
    else if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), unsigned short))         \
      tmp = (typeof(x))USHRT_MAX;                                             \
    else if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), signed int))             \
      tmp = (typeof(x))INT_MAX;                                               \
    else if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), unsigned int))           \
      tmp = (typeof(x))UINT_MAX;                                              \
    else if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), signed long))            \
      tmp = (typeof(x))LONG_MAX;                                              \
    else if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), unsigned long))          \
      tmp = (typeof(x))ULONG_MAX;                                             \
    else if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), float))                  \
      tmp = (typeof(x))FLT_MAX;                                               \
    else if (__builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(x), double))                 \
      tmp = (typeof(x))DBL_MAX;                                               \
    else                                                                      \
      abort ();                                                               \
    tmp;                                                                      \
  })


int main(void)
{
    short       num_short;
    int         num_int;
    double      num_double;
    signed char num_char;


    printf("  %ld max short\n",     TYPEOF_MAX(num_short));
    printf("  %ld max int\n",       TYPEOF_MAX(num_int));
    printf("  %f  max double\n",    TYPEOF_MAX(num_double));
    printf("  %ld max char\n",      TYPEOF_MAX(num_char));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This example uses C11 generics based on @Pedro Henrique A. Oliveira's answer,

Note, it could have more types added (`ssize_t size_t intptr_t`... etc).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define TYPEOF_MAX(x) \
    _Generic(x, \
        bool: 1, \
        char: CHAR_MAX, signed char: SCHAR_MAX, unsigned char: UCHAR_MAX, \
        signed short: SHRT_MAX, unsigned short: USHRT_MAX, \
        signed int: INT_MAX, unsigned int: UINT_MAX, \
        signed long: LONG_MAX, unsigned long: ULONG_MAX, \
        signed long long: LLONG_MAX, unsigned long long: ULLONG_MAX, \
        float: FLT_MAX, double: DBL_MAX)


#define TYPEOF_MIN(x) \
    _Generic(x, \
        bool: 0, \
        char: CHAR_MIN, signed char: SCHAR_MIN, unsigned char: 0, \
        signed short: SHRT_MIN, unsigned short: 0, \
        signed int: INT_MIN, unsigned int: 0, \
        signed long: LONG_MIN, unsigned long: 0, \
        signed long long: LLONG_MIN, unsigned long long: 0, \
        float: -FLT_MAX, double: -DBL_MAX)

/* change 100 to 1000 - static asserts work! */
_Static_assert(TYPEOF_MAX((char)4) > 100, "example check");


int main(void)
{
    short       num_short;
    int         num_int;
    double      num_double;
    signed char num_char;


    printf("  %ld max short\n",     TYPEOF_MAX(num_short));
    printf("  %ld max int\n",       TYPEOF_MAX(num_int));
    printf("  %f  max double\n",    TYPEOF_MAX(num_double));
    printf("  %ld max char\n",      TYPEOF_MAX(num_char));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to make assumptions about number representations rather than get bogged down in standards (that support architectures you're hardly likely to ever care about), you can just stuff `~0` into a variable of your target type (for unsigned types) and then assign that value to `max`.  For signed (or potentially signed) types you stuff in `~0` and check `a < 0`.  If so, assume 2's complement and go from there.  You've already decided that `long long` can hold any value of any of the types you care about, so you can stash a copy of `a` before smashing it (assuming this trick has to work given only `a`).

I just whipped up a test example to verify that this all reduces to a constant with ordinary optimization (with gcc):

```
a = ~0;
if (a < 0)  // true if a is signed
{
    a ^= 1 << (sizeof(a) * 8 - 1);  // flip sign bit to get all 1's positive
    max = a;
    min = -a - 1;
}
else
{
    max = a;
    min = 0;
}
```

Comment: this can work for the max, but what about the minimum and working for both signed/unsigned?